# Php Crawler to get the content from any website

Tags: php, web-crawler

I want to create Crawler by using php.To get events from the website.As I entered the website url it will extract the events.But having no idea.So please suggest how can we create the url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$obj = new simple_html_dom();
    $url = 'http://www.usasf.net/sanctioned/sanctioned_events/';
    $htmls = file_get_html($url);
    $tests = $htmls->find('div');
print_r($tests);
die;
```

Comment: Thanks Bhushan for your answer.
But its only works for single website.But i want it for multiple websites.

Comment: Ok Swaran , i think you have to make custom crawler for that

Comment: Okay.If any one have idea about this.Please help me out.